# Extra space on webpage created in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, spacing

I am seeing a space on the right hand side of my page, below the header that I cannot seem to move over. I would like the right side text box almost all the way to the right. This is for an HTML class that I am taking and not a real place. Any suggestions on how to make the class .right move all the way to the right of the screen?

Thank you very much.

HTML

```css
CSS
/* site.css */
body {
  background-color: #D4AD6A
}

html, body {
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

header{
 color: #256E5D;  
 background-color: #805815;
 height: 100px;
}

footer {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 40%;
  padding: 15px;
}

nav {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px
}

nav li{
  display: inline;
}

td,th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px
}

.main {
  font-family: times-new roman;
  color: yellow;
}

.title {
  color: #3B3176;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.header-image {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: -50px;
}

ul.a {
    list-style-type: none
}

.products_inline{
    font-size: 36px;
    color: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 20%;
}

a.prod_inline:link{
 color: yellow;
 font-size: 36px;
}

a.prod_inline:visited {
     color: yellow;
 font-size: 36px;
}

.inline {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
    /*border: 3px solid black;*/
}

.right {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 125px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 15px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.rightform {
  float: right;
}
.flex{
  display: flex;
}

.centerform{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 320px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: yellow;
  /*border: solid black 3px;*/
}

.page_grids{
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

table {
  width: 700px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-spacing: 0px

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Uncle's Bait and Tackle Shop Rods</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/baitstyle.css">
</head>

<body>
 <section class="main">
 <div>
  <header>
   <div class="title">Uncle's bait and tackle shop</div>
   <!--<div style="margin-left: 94%"><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></div>-->
  <nav>
          <ul>
           <li><a href="final.html">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
   <img src="img/bass1.jpg" class="header-image" />
  </header>
 </div>
 <div class="products_inline">
 <ul class="a">
   <li><a href="rods.html" class="prod_inline">Rods</a></li>
   <li><a href="lures.html" class="prod_inline">Lures</a></li>
   <li>Terminal <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tackle</li>
   <li>Clothing</li>
 </ul></div>
 </div>
 <div class="inline">
  <table class="page_grids">
   <thead>
    <th colspan="2" height: 25px>[MAKE LARGER, CENTER, USE CSS]Rods</th>
    <tr><td>Spinning Image</td><td>Our large selection of spinning rods</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Spin Casting Image</td><td>Our selection of spin casting rods are perfect 

for the novice angler and masters alike</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Baitcasting Image</td><td>Our selection of baitcasters are perfect for 

those that need precision casting</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Specialty Rods Image</td><td>Our selection of specialty rods will meet 

your needs for those species specific targets such as salmon or sturgeon</td></tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
 </div>
 <div class="right">Right side text will this wrap or keep going Right side text will this wrap or keep 

going Right side text will this wrap or keep going </div>
 </section>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: To make something stick to the right side of the screen, you can use `float:right`. Make sure to read the specs though; it is fidgety! Anyway, the reason for the placement right now is that it is an inline-block to the right of another inline-block that is 60% wide, so the space to its right varies with the window. Oh, and when the screen is narrow, the table overflows out of the "inline" div, which causes the "right" div to be on top of the table.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Is there a suggestion to not allow the overflow?

Comment: Sure, the [overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property!

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is bad ,but you should not feel bad about it.I've refactored your HTML a little so it can run properly (but its still not looking good).

HTML:

```
    <header>
        <div class="title">Uncle's bait and tackle shop</div>
        <nav>
             <ul>
                <li><a href="final.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="about_us.html">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <img src="img/bass1.jpg" class="header-image">
    </header>

    <section class="main" style="clear: both;">
        <div class="products_inline">
            <ul class="a">
                <li><a href="rods.html" class="prod_inline">Rods</a></li>
                <li><a href="lures.html" class="prod_inline">Lures</a></li>
                <li>Terminal <br>&nbsp;&nbsp;Tackle</li>
                <li>Clothing</li>
           </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="inline">
            <table class="page_grids">
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            Right side text will this wrap or keep going Right side
        </div>

    </section>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
    clear: both;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I see what you did, but I don't really understand it. Could you summarize what the clear and both do?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ - floating divs is a old school hack for positioning elements in the DOM. It would be better to use flexbox or grid (but its not widely supported).You should read more about html structure.BEM is good for naming classes - http://getbem.com/ . You can try to do your markup something like that - https://codepen.io/dakata911/pen/QOzPOx (its easier to read and you know what every section does).